# Is there a way display a shared google drive folder and "children" on a webpage? Not just files from a folder with embedded folder view?

Tags: directory

I'm looking for way to display a shared google drive folder including the subfolders on a single webpage. So far I'm using an iframe and embeddedfolderview method to display the files from an single folder. The Problem is: Once there is another folder within the first one, clicking on it takes me to google drive by opening a new tab. I want to stay on the webpage though and just browse through the files there, also being able to download them.

Is there a way of achieving this?

I'm very grateful for any kind of help, quite limited myself I'm afraid.

PS: Why am I doing this? I want to grant students of our school viewing access to some files via a protected area on our school webpage. To be able to display files from a folder on a webpage the folder's share setting need to be set to "public". Once redirected to google drive by clicking on a sub folder the link to this whole folder is in plain view and easy to copy and share around hence leaving our password protected webpage. So I want an otherwise publicly shared folder to only really be viewed on our webpage and nowhere else.

Thanks again for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Most sites; especially Google, have catch scripts to avoid malicious or intrusive scripting.

Just to let you know the Object and XMLHttpRequest methods are not working either.

I tested due to time to spare with this Coronavirus.

The best way to go is to have your own site or blog. There's some free like wordpress.com and wix.com. But this being a school access issue, not sure what they will allow.
You might want to contact your technology personnel at school to see what they tell you.

Best regards,
Ramon

Comment: Thanks Ramon. Maybe I'm lucky and some other idea pops up. Was thinking along the lines of drive API. Maybe there's a script around somewhere :-). Cheers

Comment: I have some experience with other Google API product; youtube.
Youtube allows iFrames(web) and also Mobile for Android and iOS.
As per my experience, the API only allow certain specific parameters and depends on the the used interface(Web or Mobile).


Below is the link for the details for the Google Drive API:


https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/js


I hope this helps to point you in the right direction.


Once you have something, you might want to re-formulate the question by being more specific adding the API keyword and any other issue.


Best regards,

Comment: Thanks Ramon, I really appreciate your help. I'll do that.